# Find integer in string using C# and divide it

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the integers in a .txt that I am reading in C# and divide them, but everything I have tried have not worked. Any tips?
this txt has values like this:

- this is the string in the .txt file
- queue1 6000
- queue2 54888
- queue3 1

but they change every second

- expected output
- queue1 0.6
- queue2 5.4
- queue3 0.0001

code

```
int value;
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"N:\doc\mytext.txt");
if (int.TryParse(text, out value))
        {
           value/10000;
        }
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        System.Console.WriteLine(text);
```

thanks

Comment: Can you share an example of what is located in your mytext.txt file?

Comment: As you can see, `File.ReadAllText` gives you one big block of a string. Everything in there will be in the `int.TryParse(text, out value)`. Even your words will be parsed to an integer, if possible. But that's not possible.

Comment: @Chad in the .txt file are values like this: queue1 5122, queue2 1, queue3 8000......

Comment: Please show some exact input and expected output by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Are the values on separate lines in the text file or are they separated by commas like in your comment?

Comment: @JackA. in the txt file they are separated by commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things your code needs to do:

1. Read the input
2. Find the target values in the input
3. Convert the target values into the desired result values
4. Replace the target values in the input string with the result values
5. Output the result

For this answer, I am assuming you are happy with your implementation of steps 1 and 5, so I'll only address steps 2, 3, and 4.

**Step 2: find the target values**

To find the target values in your input, you must first define what they are. According to your question and subsequent comments, your input string looks like this, with the target values bolded:

> queue1 **6000**, queue2 **54888**, queue3 **1**

These are integer values, which are embedded in your text as discrete words.

The easiest way to find them is to use a regular expression. One thing that makes your case tricky is the fact that you have numbers embedded in your text that you do not want (e.g. in "queue1"). Fortunately, [.NET regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) have a couple shortcuts that make it easy to write the necessary expression:

```
var re = new Regex(@"\b\d+\b");
```

**\b** matches a word boundary
**\d** matches any decimal digit
**+** matches one or more of the preceding characters

So this regular expression will match distinct integers like "6000" while ignoring numbers embedded in other words like "queue1".

**Step 3 - convert to desired result**

This step has a couple sub-steps

- Parse the string into a number
- Calculate the desired result number
- Format the desired result number

To parse the string into a number, you are using `int.TryParse`, which is one way to do it. Since the regular expression will find only valid integers, we can use the `Parse` method instead.

Your calculation is to divide by 10000, and you want the result to be a floating point number. If you use `10000` as your literal, the result will be an integer, so you need to do something to ensure that the result is floating point. An easy way is to use `10000.0` as your literal, like so:

```
int value = 6000;
var result = value / 10000.0; // typeof(result) == double
```

There are several options to format your output. The simplest starting point is to use the `ToString` method. The default behavior is often good enough, but if you want to specify the format, you can use [the variant that takes a format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx).

So the resulting code to parse, calculate, and format is like so:

```
(Int64.Parse(value) / 10000.0).ToString()
```

**Step 4: replace the target values in the input**

Since regular expressions are useful for finding things, they are also used to replace things. In your case, the replacement requires some logic that may not be handled by a straight regular expression (i.e., step 2). The .NET regular expression `Replace` method provides an [overload with a `MatchEvaluator` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx) for just this scenario.

Each match that is found by the regular expression is passed to the match evaluator, which is responsible for returning the string to be used as the replacement. To make things simple, you can use a lambda expression to supply the match evaluator.

So when you put it all together, you get something like this:

```
string text = @"queue1 6000, queue2 54888, queue3 1";
var re = new Regex(@"\b\d+\b");
string output = re.Replace(text, m => (Int64.Parse(m.Value) / 10000.0).ToString());
// output == "queue1 0.6, queue2 5.4888, queue3 0.0001"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! this worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions for that:

```
Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=^|\s)[0-9]+(?=$|\s)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value));
```

First, you select all parts of the string that resemble an integer, and then convert the resulting strings into integers.

`(?=$|\s)` is a **Zero-width positive lookahead assertion**. It checks if there is a whitespace or end of string at the end of the match.

`(?<=^|\s)` is a **Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion**. It checks if there is a whitespace or start of string at the beginning of the match.

You can find documentation on that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

These are necessary so that the whitespaces are not included by the matches. If they were, you'd only get one of two integers if they are only separated by one whitespace.

Comment: This will not work if the input contains text like "queue1" (see comment on OP about file content).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) to get all of the numbers in a string. The string could be the content of a file that you got from `System.IO.File.ReadAlltext` (for example).

You can use `"[0-9]+"` to get all of the integers or `"[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?"` to get both integers and floating points.

```
var pattern = "[0-9]" // or "[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?"
int[] integers = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(text, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();
// for floats
//float[] floats = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(text, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m => float.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();
```

In regular expressions you define a pattern then search the string for tokens that answer that pattern. If we need to search for integers then we can use the `"[0-9]+"` pattern. This pattern will search for all of the tokens that are between 0-9 (inclusive) with at least one character (one digit - the '+' make sure of that).
If we need to search for floating points then we need to use `"[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?"` which is composed from the integers pattern (`"[0-9]+"`) with addition to an optional floating point (`"(.[0-9]+)?"`). The '?' sign means that this token can exist zero or one time.

you can find more information about Regular Expressions and patterns [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)